# how to save bytes in C string properly?

Tags: c++, sockets, c-strings

I use winsock library to send file. The problem is that function `sendTo()` receive c string, and when I convert my file to byte array there are `\0` symbols in the middle. Because of that I can send only data that is before `\0` symbol in the string. How to fix that?

Client

```
    fstream fs;
    fs.open(txt, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    int fileSize = experimental::filesystem::file_size(txt) + 1;
    char* bytes = new char[fileSize];
    fs.read((char*)bytes, fileSize);
    sendto(sock, bytes, fileSize, 0, (sockaddr*)&clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr));
```

Comment: `sendto` actually accepts a buffer (not a c string), and its size and sends all the bytes (including 0s).  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto

Comment: Note that you don't actually create a C string, as you don't add a terminator to the data you allocate. And as @wohlstad says, you don't actually need a C-style null-terminated string, just a buffer of bytes. Which means you can skip the null-terminator and don't need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: I also recommend against using `new[]` here, and instead use a plain vector.

Comment: And please note that whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do in `(char*)bytes`) you should take that as a sign that perhaps you're doing something wrong. The problem in this case is that you do a cast that isn't needed.